# Is it safe to use a stripboard for a 22V 10000mAh LiPo circuit?

Tags: pcb, breadboard, lipo, stripboard

I have a circuit that acts as a switch between 2 LiPo batteries. I tested the circuit with 3.7V batteries on a breadboard. But now can I implement this using 22V 10000mAh LiPos on a stripboard or is the current too much ? Should I get a custom PCB instead?

Comment: Building one, or many? If you're building 5 or more and you can wait for the postman from China, I'd look at itead.cc or OSH Park or others for deals on PCBs.

Comment: I use iTead myself for prototype stuff. Good prices for a product that does the job! Nothing too special but perfect for prototyping or 1 off things

Answer (score 2):

Yeah, you should be able to do that. It depends on the amount of current that your circuit uses (Ohm's Law!)

If you are really worried, you can always put solder on the power traces, that will increase the amount of current it can handle as they will essentially be thicker traces.

Comment: You can also solder a wire along the trace -- it may be more reliable than a long solder blob.